# Update multiple records at once - REST API Call

Tags: rest-api, rest

Requirement is to update a single record at once, for which I am using a simple PATCH request using REST. The request is being made from an external platform

Sample:
URL: /services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Custom_Object__c/[OBJECT_RECORD_ID]

Data: {"Field_Name__c":"Value"}

My question here is if by any error the [OBJECT_RECORD_ID] fails to be captured and the call gets made without it. Would it update all/multiple records on Salesforce? Or, would it fail? Are there any specific security concerns I should be aware of?

If all the records are needed to be updated/patched, is there any way to do so?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will get a JSON exception when you try to do REST on a null record Id. It wouldnt update all records.

Answer (score 1):

- If no Id is specified, the call would fail with the HTTP error 405:
  `METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`
- If the Id is "null", the call would fail with
  the HTTP error 404: `NOT_FOUND`

To update multiple records at once, follow the instructions here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_update.htm